# displaying different text when changing the picker in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, get, fetch, picker

I created my apps using react native CRNA and I want to display a text from an array. I want the text to change depend on the selected picker, so the index is the same with the picker key.

Here is my snippet code

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            branches: [],
        }
    }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('someURL', {
            method: 'GET',
        })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({
          cabang: responseJson.data,
          loading: true,
          })
          responseJson.forEach((item)=>{
          this.state.cabang.push({
           branch_id:item.branch_id,
           name: item.name,
           address: item.address,
          })
          })
          branches.map((items)=>{console.log(item.name)})
          console.log(responseJson);
          return responseJson;
      })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
  render() 
  {
    const branchesName = this.state.branches.map((item, branch_id)=> {
      return(
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>)
    });
    const branchesPicker = this.state.branches.map((item, branch_id)=> {
      return(
            <Picker.Item
            label={item.name}
            value={item.name}
            key={this._keyExtractor}/>
        )
    });
    return (
      <Text>{branchesName}</Text>
      <Picker selectedValue={this.state.branches.name}
          mode="dropdown"
          style={{ height: 50, justifyContent: 'space-around', flex:4, alignItems: 'stretch', }}
          onValueChange={(item, branch_id)=> this.setState({name: item})}>
      {branchesPicker}
      </Picker>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried this code but the result is showing all of the data from array not one by one. I get so stuck to find a way to display it one by one according to the selected picker... can anyone please help me??

Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your render method, you are mapping over the list of arrays and returning an array of `<Text>` elements.

`const branchesName = this.state.branches.map((item, branch_id)=> {
      return(
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>)
});`

If you just want to show the selected array item, you can change ( in your render method )

`<Text>{branchesName}</Text>`

to

`<Text>{this.state.name}</Text>`

This is because in the Picker element, whenever you are changing the selected picker, you are assigning that to your component's state under the property name.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer.. my code is working fine now. but i want to add another text which is address that also needs to change depends on the selected picker. do you know what should i do? because if i put <Text>{this.state.address}</Text> it's not showing anything...